# How to query IPv6 NDP (neighbor discovery protocol) table for a specific neighbor

Tags: linux, ipv6, arp, netlink

I am using Linux and trying to figure out how to query (via an API) the NDP table for a specific entry.  The only example I have found so far (in the source for iproute2) uses Netlink and gets the entire table.  Is there a way to query Netlink for a specific IPv6 addr on a specific interface?  Or is there a different way than using Netlink that I should be going about doing it?

Comment: Could you maybe share your way to get the neighbour table? I am too looking for a way to query the table.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible in the Linux kernel as of version 3.6. There was a [patch someone submitted](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/42976/) back in 2010 to add such a feature, but it was never merged into the kernel code base. You have to pull the entire neighbor table into user space and then do the searching of it there.